# I want to take a screen shot of a chart from trading view at my order fill times which are in an excel sheet, how can I automate this process

Tags: automation, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, journaling

My strategy is scalping and do many trades in a day, later after the market close I use the bar replay feature to go back and take a screenshot to add my comments for my trade journal, it’s quite cumbersome to do for multiple trades, is there a way to automate this process so that I just give the order fill times in an excel sheet/csv and it takes the screen shots automatically and saves them at a specified location? I was thinking to use pine script, any other ideas are also appreciated. Thank you in advance!

was doing it manually

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pinescript.
I personnaly use the camera button on the top right of the chart screen to get a link :
[image]

and choose copy link to image, and paste this link to my journal (Tradingview take a screenshot of your screen and create a link to this screenshot).